# MySQL Charset issue on Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding, laravel

I have a charset issue about insert into with laravel to MySQL.

Here are my **app/database.php** config:

```
'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => '127.0.0.1',
        'database'  => 'article',
        'username'  => 'root',
        'password'  => '9cqcs57q',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_turkish_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
),
```

This is database table :

```
2   title   text    utf8_turkish_ci 
3   content longtext    utf8_unicode_ci
```

I write **türkçe başlığı** from input form.
This is what I see on **title**  and **content** table:

```
t&uuml;rk&ccedil;e başlığı
&lt;p&gt;t&uuml;rk&ccedil;e başlığı&lt;/p&gt;
```

And my controller:

```
$makale = new Article;
$makale->title              = e(Input::get('baslik'));
$makale->content            = e(Input::get('icerik'));
$makale->header             = $adres;
$makale->save();
```